# recognize that user call somebody

Tags: iphone, ios4, phone-call

how to regognize that user call somebody from code?(means i have an app and want to do sth when user call somebody)

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that I'm afraid, firstly your app won't be running when they are calling someone and secondly you can't access the phone functions from the SDK.  Might be possible with a background process on a jail broken phone.

Comment: is it possible with local notification?

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible, not through code nor through notifications. You can't do anything to stop this, when a phonecall comes in, your application gets suspended, like as if you'd press home in iOS 4 and it will multitask if it has been programed to do so. Have a look at the `UIApplication` implementations for multitasking and do your work there.